# Encrypt with SHA512 algorithm to byte array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, hash, unpack, sha512

I have to hash the password for using an API with authentication.
the code snippet for hashing is in the documentation, which is as follows:

```
$password = "[".implode(',',unpack('C*', hash('sha512', $pwd, true)))."]";
```

the code snippet return something like "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]"

I put the password to an object (the class implements *\JsonSerializable*)

```
$apiCall->setPassword($password);
```

but when i json_encode the object, i got the password like this:

```
"Password":"[149,239,56,211,172,179,...]"
```

the problem is the quotation mark **"**. How can i remove, and pass the password to $apiCall as array, and not as string?

```
"Password": [149,239,56,211,172,179,...]
```

**UPDATE**
Why don't I use the simply the unpack result, which is an array?

```
$password = unpack('C*', hash('sha512', $pass, true));
```

and after json_encode the password will be

```
"Password":{"1":149,"2":239,"3":56,"4":211,"5":172,..}"
```

but I need the format described a few lines above.

Comment: Well, yes, you're creating a string! How about creating an array instead, basically what `unpack` already gives you?

Comment: OK, now you just want to remove the keys from the associative array: [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values).